# website doesn't display with domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, url

I have a website that up until this morning was displaying fine on a domain name. This morning however it seems to have gone down. I can access the website fine through the server IP address, just not the domain name.

The DNS settings with the domain name company are fine also. They haven't been changed. Is there anything else I can check for?

any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Impossible to debug without the actual domaine name. It can be many things. Anyway, see http://www.bortzmeyer.org/tests-dns.html for testing tools.

Comment: @bortzmeyer, apologies. I didn't want anyone to debug it. It was just a general "is there anything else I can do" type question. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing an nslookup for the fqdn from your own computer?  Just because the primary name server are working doesn't mean your DNS lookups to a different server are returning the correct details.

Remember also that your computer will check hosts file for a domain name, then the first DNS server in your settings.  If the first DNS server returns ANY kind of response, **including that it couldn't find a record**, then the DNS lookups stop.

Eliminate any DNS causes for the problem, and if that doesn't show any issues, check the web server is handling the hostname in the request properly - but if you didn't change anything I'd say 99% chance it is DNS issue.

Comment: @dunxd..thanks for the reply. The problem seemed to correct itself after an email to the domain name registration company. Seems it was a problem at their end. thanks :)